# WPF/C# - Throw away the Content for a Checkbox in a Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox

TL;DR How do I make a Checkbox not draw/include the label for the content or the space required for the label?

I'm using Visual Studio in conjunction with C# and WPF.  I have a Checkbox in a DataTemplate inside of a DataGrid. My issue is that I suspect that while the Content is empty, the space for the content is still being taken up.

The end result is that I have a checkbox smashed to the left of the column, and a vast desert of whitespace to it's right

My current UI disaster looks like this:

[image: Current UI]

Right now, my XAML looks like the following.  As you can see, I've tried messing around with the Horizontal and HorizontalContentAlignments with little to no luck.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Y/N">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
         <TextBlock>
         </TextBlock>
       </CheckBox>
     </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I've tried setting the size of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` but I don't see it really centering the checkbox even with the Horizontal* attributes set which makes me think it's got the space for the Label in there.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>` does center the checkboxes in the column. Is it this, what you want?

Comment: @Rekshino There is no HorizontalAlignment property for the Checkbox

Comment: :) [CheckBox Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.checkbox?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Y/N" Width="50">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
         <TextBlock>
         </TextBlock>
       </CheckBox>
     </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Insert Width into DataGridTemplateColumn

or

```
 <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Y/N" Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
```

You can use this way